# Portable storage: do I have to re-grant app permissions when switching microSD cards?

Tags: external-sd, stock-android, permissions, file-permissions

I'm using a Moto Z2 Force running Android 7.1.1 with a 128 GB microSD card installed. I wanna upgrade to a 400 GB card. Would I have to re-grant microSD access app permissions for the new card, or do those permissions cover any card inserted into the phone?

Answer (score 0):

The permissions should cover any SD card.

But your phone's max SD size is 256 GB, see http://www.gsmarena.com/motorola_moto_z2_force-8693.php

Comment: Thanks, you were right about the permissions. However, generally speaking phones with microSD slots support cards of any size. The 400 GB card is working just fine for me.

Comment: Really? didn't know that!

Comment: Yeah it's uncommon knowledge. I'm not sure why OEMs listed size limits in specs; maybe it's for power draw reasons.